# Не присваивается значение строке

Tags: stl, строки, c++

Хочу распарсить строку вида 127.0.0.1:556 на ip и порт. Делаю следующее

```
#define DEFAULT_INTERFACE "0.0.0.0"
#define DEFAULT_PORT 27000

const char* iface = DEFAULT_INTERFACE;
int port = DEFAULT_PORT;
size_t colonPos = str.find(":");
port = atoi(str.substr(colonPos + 1, str.size() - colonPos).c_str());
std::cout << "test1: " << argumentValue.substr(0, colonPos).c_str() << std::endl;
iface = argumentValue.substr(0, colonPos).c_str();
std::cout << "test2: iface " << iface << " port " << port << std::endl;
```

Вывод следующий

test1: 127.0.0.1

test2: iface port 556

Почему iface пустая строка? Это по виндой. Под линуксом это работает нормально, но если получать сначала iface, затем port то оба значения равны 556

Comment: @KoVadim, уже написал Вам, почему интерфейс не виден.

Хотел бы добавить, что в любом случае наверное надо бы проверять, что ":" есть в строке. Если оставить тип iface char \*, то видимо надо так

    if (colonPos != string::npos) {
       port = atoi(str.c_str() + colonPos + 1); // atoi() сама уткнется в nil в конце c_str()
       iface = strndup(argumentValue.c_str(), colonPos); // здесь colonPos будет как раз равен длине подстроки iface
    }

не очень понимаю, почему Вы работаете то с `str`, то с `argumentValue`, но видимо так надо. а вот все лишние буковки (substr и т.п. тут ни к чему).

Comment: Запустите в дебаге и просмотрите что и как у Вас присваивается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это ещё хорошо, что она пустая. В строке

```
iface = argumentValue.substr(0, colonPos).c_str();
```

создается временный объект (функцией substr), от которой вызывается c_str. Указатель, полученный таким образом, живет до конца строки. В следующей строке там будет мусор.

Лучше писать где то так:

```
std::string iface = DEFAULT_INTERFACE;
int port = DEFAULT_PORT;
size_t colonPos = str.find(":");
port = atoi(str.substr(colonPos + 1, str.size() - colonPos).c_str());
std::cout << "test1: " << argumentValue.substr(0, colonPos) << std::endl;
iface = argumentValue.substr(0, colonPos);
std::cout << "test2: iface " << iface << " port " << port << std::endl;
```

рекомендация: не используйте без надобности `c_str()` и `char*`.